# TFS build notifications for specific builds & for multiple users

Tags: tfs

http://caniruddha.wordpress.com/2010/02/08/tfs-build-notification-in-tfs-power-tool/ explains how to set email notifications for ALL the builds in a team project OR how to set email notifications for specific builds for yourself only.

What I would like to know is how to set build notifications for specific builds & multiple users.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Team Foundation Server build Tools allows to set up build notifications for multiple builds and **ALL** users. I don't think there is anything that allows you to set up notifications for multiple builds and a set of users
[image]

Comment: I'm getting notifications for a subset of our builds. This is not set on my machine (dialog above), meaning someone set this up centerly.

Comment: Yes, notifications can be set from TFS or using TFS Power Tools. You are using TFS. The above mechanism give you more granularity but you need to install TFS Power Tools for your machine

Comment: Thanks for your time, just want to understand: Since notifications are not set on my machine/TFS power tools -> they are set in TFS. Since I get notifications only for some of the builds -> a subset is set to send me notifications. Since only few users get notified for these builds -> a subset of users are configured in TFS. But in TFS I only found the options of setting notifications for ALL builds.